# Magento 1.9 - How to get grand total in Mage_Payment_Block_Info

Tags: magento-1.9, grand-total

I'm looking for how to get grand total in `Mage_Payment_Block_Info.phtml`.
I know grandtotal comes from `$quote` so i was trying to bring this data to `Mage_Payment_Block_Info.php`. But I can't find answer!

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/payment/info/default.phtml

```
#1 . 
<?php echo number_format(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(), 2) ?>
#2 . 
<?php echo number_format(Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(),2) ?> 
#3 . 
<?php echo number_format(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal(), 2) ?>


#4 . 
<?php print_r(Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData('grand_total')) ?>
<?php $grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
echo $grandTotal?>
```

I tested above them but they don't work. Do i have to declare that i use `checkout model` in `Mage_Payment_Block_Info.phtml`. If it is, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

**Write a function at** `Mage_Payment_Block_Info` at

```
pulbic function getGrantTotalAmount(){

    if ($this instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment) {
         $grand_total = $this->getOrder()->getGrandTotal();
     } else {
         $grand_total = $this->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
     }
    return $grand_total ;
   }
```

***Then at your phtml file call this function***